How 2 bytes can produce negative number, mind blowing?
I am trying to use LoRAWAN and sending tempurature values as less bytes. I found that way and tested it works fine it can send negative and positive numbers as 2 bytes instead of "float" as 4 bytes or "double" as 8 bytes but still I can not understood how this code produce int celciusInt = (bytes[0] & 0x80 ? 0xFFFF0000 : 0) | bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1]; negative numbers. as a result it makes 4 bytes for nagetive numbers but ttn network still see this as 2 bytes and mind blowing
TEST code:
byte bytes[2];
int derece = -3556;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(3000);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  bytes[0] = derece >> 8;
  bytes[1] = derece & 0xFF;

  int celciusInt = (bytes[0] & 0x80 ? 0xFFFF0000 : 0) | bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1];

  Serial.println(celciusInt);

  delay(3000);
}


OUTPUT:
-3556

As a result -3556 number is returning 0xFFFFF0E4 value and how this make negative numbers still I did not understant. So many times I read chatgpt or etc. but still not understood.
Can you explain it to me like you would to a 5-year-old?

how would you encode negative numbers? the sign in the first bit for example?

In reality computers doesn't know numbers, just bits (high and low). Then some arithmetic operations may be added on a CPU, but with a well known bit encoding (and it depends on the data). Integers (so signed) may be encoded with sign-bit, 1-complement, 2-complement (and for sure more methods). floats have totally different encoding, BCD (now seldom) are a mix bag. On youtube Ben Eatan describe basic of electronics until building a simple CPU (I think in one or two videos go also on arithmetic and encoding). The series is very long (but you get all, nothing hidden).

is it still mind blowing if you think How 2 bytes can represent negative number?

@jsotola Still reading ;) I am reading the assignment that Edgar Bonet gave me. If the number is signed, the first bit indicates whether it is negative or positive. If the number is unsigned, the first bit is considered as a normal number. The maximum value for an int16_t is 32767, but for a uint16_t it is 65535. In short, the number does not become negative; it becomes positive or negative depending on how we define the number type

... Continue, For example, the number -55 in binary is 11001001, but when we enter this binary value into a calculator, it outputs 201. Why? Because the calculator always assumes the number is positive.

this might help ... https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html?x=8000 .... https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html?x=FF00

I won't explain it like you are 5-years old because it would take to
much effort, you are a grown up, and you are capable of reading articles
yourself. So start by putting aside ChatGPT, and instead read the
Wikipedia article Two's complement. I mean, read carefully,
taking all the time you need to reach a complete understanding.
Now, the number −3556 would be written in binary as either
11110010.00011100

or
11111111.11111111.11110010.00011100

depending on whether your Arduino uses 16-bit or 32-bit integers (it
varies across Arduino boards). The assignments to bytes[0] and
bytes[1] extract the two least-significant bytes of this number:
bytes[0] = 11110010 (in binary)
bytes[1] = 00011100 (in binary)

The assignment to celciusInt reconstructs the number by ORing together
three terms:
11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000 = (bytes[0] & 0x80 ? 0xFFFF0000 : 0)
00000000.00000000.11110010.00000000 = bytes[0] << 8
00000000.00000000.00000000.00011100 = bytes[1]
───────────────────────────────────
11111111.11111111.11110010.00011100 → assigned to celciusInt

Note that the first term in sign extension (you know what this is,
because you read the article I mentioned, didn't you?). It is only
needed if you want the result as a 32-bit integer. It would be simpler
to forego sign extension and instead store the result in a 16-bit
integer:
int16_t celciusInt = uint16_t(bytes[0]) << 8 | bytes[1];

Note that the code may work even without the cast of bytes[0] to
uint16_t: this cast is only needed to avoid signed integer overflow,
which in C++ is undefined behavior.
Edit: Note that a yet simpler way to split and reconstruct the
number is to use a union. This lets you have a 16-bit integer and an
array of two bytes share the same memory. You can then write to the
integer and read back the bytes or vice-versa:
// A 16-bit integer and a pair of bytes sharing their memory.
union {
    int16_t value;
    uint8_t bytes[2];
} packet;

// Split a 16-bit integer in two bytes.
packet.value = -3556;
Serial.println(packet.bytes[0]);  // -> 28
Serial.println(packet.bytes[1]);  // -> 242

// Reconstruct a 16-bit integer from its bytes.
packet.bytes[0] = 214;
packet.bytes[1] = 255;
Serial.println(packet.value);  // -> -42

Beware of endianness though: unlike in the previous code, bytes[0]
here is the least-significant byte. Practically every Arduino and
computer in use today is little-endian, so this may not be an issue.
However, there are some communication protocols that are big-endian, so
you should be aware of the issue.

Re:  int16_t celciusInt = uint16_t(bytes[0]) << 8 | bytes[1]; You still have the potential for overflow even with the cast, it's just an overflow you get while storing result into the int16_t celciusInt rather than while calculating the result of the bit-wise or.

@timemage: Nope. Storing an out-of-range value in an integer is not technically considered an “overflow”, and is perfectly legit. Actually, it is implementation-defined until C++20, but GCC, like any sane compiler, does the only sensible thing.

@EdgarBonet that makes sense now

@EdgarBonet I guess I just have it in the category of "non-portable". But it is nice that they've codified the common behaviour in a newer standard.

@EdgarBonet I think union can not working with in javascript. Such as I am sending data from arduino to lorawan network (TTN) there is payload formatter. whatelse I tried union can not defined. So I am using for converting at TTN var celciusInt =  uint16_t(bytes[16]) << 8 | bytes[15];

@mehmet: If you want to decode a binary packet in JavaScript, the right tool is a DataView. This lets you extract numbers from any standard C type (uint8_t, int16_t...) at an arbitrary offset in the buffer, with the endianness you want. E.g. let response = await fetch(data_url); let buffer = await response.arrayBuffer(); let view = new DataView(buffer); let celciusInt = view.getInt16(15, true);

I suspect you mixed-up with the Endianness. I've seen many people get it wrong when they deal with Lora communication.
For Lora communication, data are send in Big Endian, while Arduino (and almost all modern computers) are storing data in Little Endian.
So if you are sending an integer 7410 (which is 0x1cf2 in hex) via Lora, 0x1c get send first, followed by 0xf2. However, when stored in the Arduino, if you are storing the data based on the transmission sequence, you would end-up storing 0x1c as first byte in data[0], and 0xfc as the 2nd byte in data[1]. So the data would looks like as 0xf21c when retrieve from Arduino in Little Endian manner, 0xf21c is  the 2-compliment of -3556 in a sign integer!
